# Goodness of Fit expected value

Tags: statistics

If I have a classical experiment with peas, where in the experiment there are hybrids produced in such a way that probabilities of observing the different phenotypes are:

Round and Yellow: 9/16

Round and Green: 3/16

Angular and yellow: 3/16

Angular and green: 1/16

If I choose 20 hybrids at random, how would I calculate the expected number of plants to show each phenotype?  Then if I let Y=number of plants having round and yellow, how would I find the Variance of Y? Would I just take my answer from the first question, square it and then use the formula for variance to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $Y$ has binomial distribution, $n-20$, $p=9/16$. By the standard formula for the mean and variance of the binomial, we have $E(Y)=(20)(9/16)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)=(20)(9/16)(7/16)$.

**Remark:** The general binomial, $n$ independent trials, probability of success $p$ on any trial has mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$. The easiest way to derive these formulas is to let $X_i=1$ if we get a success on the $i$-th trial, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number of successes $Y$ is given by $Y=X_1+\cdots +X_n$.

Formulas for mean and variance now follow, since the mean of a sum is the sum of the means, and the variance of a sum of *independent* random variables is the sum of the variances.